# Extract variables from string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this and I need to save the values of y, x, z into 3 float variables.Length and sign of the three numbers are not constant.

```
{'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: A string? Or a dictionary? If you really have a string like that, I would say the first step is to parse it into a dictionary, using JSON or suchlike.

Comment: if a = {'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026}     var=[ float(a[key]) for key in a]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply convert that to a `dict` like this, with [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval("{'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026}")
print type(data)
```

**Output**

```
<type 'dict'>
```

And then you can access the values of `x`, `y` and `z` like this

```
print data['x'], data['y'], data['z']
```

Comment: +1-- I had never heard of that module.

Comment: @CodyPiersall Try this http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html. Basically, `literal_eval` is literaly evaluating the string and thats why its able to detect that its dealing with a `dict` here.

Comment: Do you think it's worth mentioning that `literal_eval` is safe?  Meaning it will only evaluate "strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None." (from the docs)

Comment: @CodyPiersall Included reference to `ast.literal_eval` :)

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it really is a string, you can parse it with json (or with `eval` which I wouldn't want to suggest):

```
import json
s = "{'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026}".replace ("'", '"')
d = json.loads (s)
x, y, z = d ['x'], d ['y'], d ['z']
print (x, y, z)
```

Comment: If that's really what the string looks like, I think `ast.literal_eval` might be the best bet.

Comment: Probably, but I always get itchy with `eval` even when it is `literal`. A childhood trauma I guess.

Comment: Well, as fears go, that's a pretty reasonable one.  More like being afraid of swimming near shark-infested waters than afraid of water..

Answer (score 0):

Once you have converted the string into a Python dictionary as explained in the other answers, using `json` or `ast`, you could do this to add all the variables in the dictionary to your global variables:

```
>>> data = {'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026} # your parsed dictionary
>>> globals().update(data)
>>> print x
-1.0188
```

Here, `globals()` gets you a dictionary holding all the globally defined variables and functions, and with `update` you simply add the names and values in the `data` dictionary to those.

If you have just `x`, `y` and `z` this is surely overkill, but it can be handy if you have more variables in the dict/string, as you do not have to do `x = data["x"]` for all of them. Of course you should be sure that those variables will not overwrite important builtin functions and similar.

Answer (score -1):

```
import collections
a=collections.OrderedDict({'y': 0.02, 'x': -1.0188, 'z': 2.026})
[y,x,z]=[ float(a[key]) for key in a]
```

Comment: You've got no guarantee that `x` corresponds to `'x'` if you do this, though; `for key in a` will iterate over the keys in some arbitrary order.

Comment: In that case, he can use an ordered dictionary